# How to do JSON transformation in python?

Tags: python, json

I have done JSON transformation using this demo website

http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

I even got the Json spec ready

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "r_id": "r_id",
      "data": {
        "list": {
          "*": {
            "uid": "uid",
            "item_list": {
              "*": {
                "p_id": "p_id",
                "sku": "sku",
                "q": "q",
                "pr": "pr"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I can seem to find a python package to do this,
all available packages are in `Java`,
Is there any **`pythonic`** way to do this transformation ?

Comment: It might be nearly as easy or even easier to implement this transformation by hand in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has an [apposite standard library to deal with JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Here is how you can transform JSON to Python:

```
import json
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
y = json.loads(x)
print(y["name"])
```

###### Output

```
John
```